# Google Earth Engine - Masked raster loses resolution on export?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using a mask function in Earth Engine to restrict a raster to only the relevant pixels for my analysis (those close to freshwater).

[image: Here is the mask]

This results in rasters clipped to the relevant region of interest, which looks correct and has the correct resolution. [image: Image at correct resolution]

However when I export that as an asset using the following code:

```
Export.image.toAsset({ 
    image: predictors, 
    description: 'predictors', 
    scale: GrainSize, 
    region: AOI, 
    maxPixels: 1e10, 
    shardSize: 16, });
```

The exported image is blocked off in a strange way and is missing tons of information and improperly masked. [image: Image has forest pixels not aligning with the black and white mask]

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Is it something with my export settings?

Reproducible Example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/efe7924e96b522831ac9b46e49b6241c

Comment: Hi Connor, the reproducible example doesn't work, so can you share the collections, or add a new example?

Comment: Hi- I believe that should be fixed now! Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Let me know if it still does not work.